# Call template function for the value of a pointer out of a template function, in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11

I am trying to call a template function for the pointer that was given as template parameter in my calling function. My code is:

```
template <>
struct serialize_helper<std::string> {
     // not important code...
    }

};

template <class T>
inline void serializer(const T& obj, StreamType::iterator& res) {

    if(std::is_pointer<T>::value)
    {
        //THIS doesn' work
        serialize_helper<*T>::apply(*obj,res);
    }
    else
        serialize_helper<T>::apply(obj,res);

}
```

If I call:

```
std::string test("test");
serializer(test, res);
```

everything works fine.
But I want also to be able to call the serializer with a pointer as obj:

```
std::string test* = new std::string("test");
serializer(test, res);
```

Dereferencing the pointer before calling the serializer function is not a possible option, please do not propose that. Inside the serializer function it is possible.

Shorter description: I want to call `serializer` with a `std::string*` and have that do the same thing has if I'd called it with the `std::string` it points to.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as the error messages you come across.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole body of your template function needs to compile for the types it's instantiated with, regardless of whether or not a branch will ever be taken. To get around this issue, you can define separate functions for when `T` is a pointer and when it's not.

Using SFINAE:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = nullptr>
inline void serializer(const T& obj, StreamType::iterator& res) {
    serialize_helper<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::apply(*obj,res);
}

template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = nullptr>
inline void serializer(const T& obj, StreamType::iterator& res) {
    serialize_helper<T>::apply(obj,res);
}
```

Using tagged-dispatch:

```
template <class T>
inline void serializer(const T& obj, StreamType::iterator& res, std::true_type) {
    serialize_helper<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::apply(*obj,res);
}

template <class T>
inline void serializer(const T& obj, StreamType::iterator& res, std::false_type) {
    serialize_helper<T>::apply(obj,res);
}

template <class T>
inline void serializer(const T& obj, StreamType::iterator& res) {
    serializer(obj, res, std::is_pointer<T>());
}
```

Comment: I get it with your second example, but i use:
serialize_helper<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::apply(*obj, res);
instead of 
serialize_helper<std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::apply(*obj, res);

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with something like

```
template <class T>
inline void serializer(const T& obj, StreamType::iterator& res) {
    serialize_helper<T>::apply(obj,res);
}

template<class T>
inline void serializer(T* obj, StreamType::iterator& res) {
    serialize_helper<T>::apply(*obj,res);
}
```

Comment: @StheKing Works fine for me too. [An exemple](http://ideone.com/EDRpMh) that looks even more like your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::remove_pointer` to do that with `std::enable_if`.

```
template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
inline void serializer(const T& obj) {
    serialize_helper<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::apply(*obj);
}

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
inline void serializer(const T& obj) {
    serialize_helper<T>::apply(obj);
}
```

Note that I've removed the `StreamType` for simplicity.

[**live demo**](http://ideone.com/2JG4yL)

Comment: I think that'd need to be `typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type`, or `std::remove_pointer_t<T>` in C++14.

Comment: Good points! I still need some practice on that but my edit should present something decent hopefully.